# How to create a new "TextView" object,by concatenating two strings?

Tags: android

I want to create a new "TextView" object in "MainActivity" code by concatenating
Two String names. for example:

```
String s1 = "num";
String s2 = "ber";
String s3 = s1+s2;
TextView s3 = new TextView(this);
```

How cast s3 to TextView object,so i dont get anyy error,code above?
I mean i want to use s3 as a "TextView" name object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. You can't have variables that share names in the same scope. You can't cast Strings to TextViews. You have to use the `setText()` method on a TextView.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(s3);
```

or

```
TextView s3 = new TextView(this);
s3.setText(s1 + s2);
```

or programmatically in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(s3); //set textview id, this WILL NOT make it a variable of 'number'
    linearLayout.addView(textView);

}
```

Comment: No i do't want to sho s3 text. i want use s3 as a TextView name.

Comment: if you are using s1, s2, s3 are variable names then you have a lot more to be worried about than using the same variable name. Variable names can not be the same name, only method names as long as they return something different like a string or int. Please, for the love the god, use better names for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is you declared 2 variables with the same name. Fix it by giving TextView a better name and then as @soldforapp answered already, set the text using the method `.setText();`

edit:

Wait, so you want to assign the value of the TextView to the string variable s3?
I don't really understand your problem. If so, if your code would look like this (so it runs)

```
String s1 = "num";
String s2 = "ber";
String s3 = s1+s2;
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

This line will assign the variable s3 the text inside your TextView.

```
s3 = tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I know using two same name for  different types is not correct. but problem is what could be replace by s3 ,so TextView s3 = new TextView(this); change to TextView number = new TextView(this);

Comment: First of all, using the same name is bad and going to throw an error even if you declare the same type. After you did the changes as you said, you only have to update the value of the TextView with s3 as someone said already.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same name for the different variable in one scope is not possible in JAVA. (even with different types)

Using `StringBuilder` is better option than concatenating with `+` operation, so:

```
String s1 = "num";
String s2 = "ber";
String concat = new StringBuilder().append(s1).append(s2).toString();

TextView s3 = new TextView(this);
s3.setText(concat);
```

Edit:
What you want is not as easy as what exists in script languages like PHP but you can do it with reflection with efforts. But there is an easier option with using `Map`:

```
Map<String,TextView> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(concat, new TextView(this));
```

You can get the `TextViews` with:

`map.get(concat).setText("Your String");`

Comment: @M.JJalali What do you want to do that? What is your use case? See edited answer. It may help you.

Comment: Its clear, i want s1+s2 be name of TextView object,rather than concat name that you used for declaring Textview.how could create this Textview:(TextView number = new TextView(this);),number is s1+s2

Comment: Consider my final answer.

Comment: you can not use a String value as a variable for an object. @M.JJalali

Comment: Do you know how could create multiple TextViews in a for loop?if can so you answer my question.

Comment: @M.JJalali edited answer. you would do it normally. you can add different things to the textview, like textsize, id, etc etc etc.